# How to combining similar git repositories?

Tags: git, repository-design

I have migrated an big old cvs repository to git. In my project I have several different development teams, which need access to the same or different repository folders. So my idea is to separate the central repository into several repositories, so that each team would have access to one repository with the folders they need. Behind these repositories an integration repository would be necessary.

So the problem is that there are project folders to which several teams need access. For example:

```
Team-repo 1: folderA, folderB, folderD
Team-repo 2: folderC, folderD
-->Shared repo (repo1 + repo2): folderA, folderB, folderC, folderD
```

In this example folder D has to be combined.
Is it possible in git to implement such a concept?

My intention is, that each development team only need to clone one little repository instead of the big one.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have each "folder" in its own repository (at least each independant folder).

Then you use the concept of submodules ( http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules )

- "modules" repository : RepoA, RepoB, RepoC, RepoD
- "project" repository, using `git submodule` : Team1, Team 2

If you look at the url I provided, workflow is described.

Comment: i never got happy with submodules that are not rather static third-party libraries. the overhead for updating several fast-changing submodules is insane imho.

Comment: True, it all depends on the process and stability : I used it to work on "one module" while keeping the other stable then upgrade the other ones, works like that if your APIs are stable enough

Comment: But a commit to a submodule does not update the remote repository (superproject). So this would be too complex in my view. So is there any other chance to implement such a scenario?